# memory leak that i cant seem to solve

Tags: ios4, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

So analyzer is now telling me i have a memory leak. In the function below it says 'potential leak of an object allocated into 'theAudio'

I think it speaks the truth because the app works well for a few minutes then slowly crashes.

I've tried 'autorelease' but it tells me 'object sent autorelease too many times'.

Sorry to be a pest but does anybody have any ideas on this?

```
-(void) playFile:(NSString*) nameOfFile { // plays audio file passed in by a string

    fileLocation = nameOfFile;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:nameOfFile ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL       fileURLWithPath: path] error:NULL];
[theAudio play];
[fileLocation release];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used this, but you probably need to keep a `retain` on the player (as you do) but then `release` it when you're done with it, e.g., when you get one of the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` methods (so you need to implement the player's `delegate.)